# How do I use variables in VLOOKUP in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I need to use a vlookup function where I would get all the arguments from different functions and use them here.

Eg:  `ActiveCell.Formula= “=VLOOKUP(B2, ‘sheet 2’!$A:$I, 4, FALSE)`

I would like to write this as:

```
VLOOKUP(element, f_range, col_num, true_false)
```

Currently, I only want the column to be dynamic, but in the future, I would require all these to be dynamic.

Comment: When you write a formula you do it between "" because its a literal string which will be outputed to an excel cell. To use variables you need to write them out of the  quotes. i.e. `"=VLOOKUP(" & element & "," & f_range & "," & col_num & "," true_false & ")"` don't forget the commas because they are aswell on the formula. `&` is a concatenate operator, it will put together everything you are joining with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write a formula you do it between "" because its a literal string which will be outputed to an excel cell. To use variables you need to write them out of the quotes.

i.e. `"=VLOOKUP(" & element & "," & f_range & "," & col_num & "," true_false & ")"`

Don't forget the commas because they are aswell on the formula. & is a concatenate operator, it will put together everything you are joining with it.

There is another way if you are willing to have values instead the formulas on your cells:

`ActiveCell.Value = Application.VLOOKUP(element, f_range, col_num, true_false)`

This will calculate the value and put it to your cell. No need to concatenate anything, just give it the parameters as variables.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, both of them workded well. I would like to use the second method, but the first one, even though it seems trickier is better for my project.

Comment: @Saij glad to help. Consider marking the answer as correct so others may find it easier :)